# What is the correct position of the preposition "before" in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, word-order

Which position of the preposition *before* in the following sentences is correct?

> Please be at the venue at least before 10 minutes.

or

> Please be at the venue at least 10 minutes before meeting start.

Comment: A 3rd alternative - "Please be at the venue at least 10 minutes early"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Before* should stay together with its **object** (the **object** of the *preposition*). In this sentence, the object is **the meeting**, so the sentence will be written thus:

> Please be at the venue at least 10 minutes *before* **the meeting**.

Comment: Then my understanding, "the meeting" is object of before preposition, right?

Comment: @CharmiSapariya Yes, that is correct. I will add that detail to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please be at the venue at least **ten** minutes before **the** meeting **starts**.

Your first sentence, "..before ten minutes..." does not express what the ten minutes is *before*.  It is *before the meeting* , which is why the second structure is correct.